# Are there any simple programs for 3D fractal visualization?

Tags: 3d, visualization, fractals

Preferably with a source code, but algorithm description would be enough.

Comment: +1 for "simple" and "3D fractal visualization" in same sentence

Comment: Actually one of my fellow students wrote very short program in OCaml + OpenGL visualizing Julia set in 3D. It was around 3-4 screens of code. Only thing I remember is that he used quaternions.

Answer (score 1):

POV-Ray can render three-dimensional cross-sections of four-dimensional Julia sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Quat - A 3D-Fractal-Generator](http://www.physcip.uni-stuttgart.de/phy11733/quat_e.html)

Comment: Now optimized for a Pentium `III`!

Comment: hey, nobody said that must be a recent version; I know about Quat existence since '93 =)

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but this seems to be a pretty decent software regarding real 3d fractals: http://www.incendia.net/

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, your question depends on what type you are interested in: 
Is it julia sets/mandelbrot sets, and their higher-dimensional relatives,
OR
is it IFS (such as Flame fractals) in 3 dimensions?

The algorithms are very different, and yields very different results.